# Where to put SDF file in the Solution and how to write the "data source" in App.config?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-ce, telerik-open-access

I'm using a SQL Server CE `.sdf` database file and I configure this database in the `app.config` using this `<connectionStrings>` tag:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ReviewsDBConnection" 
         connectionString="data source=&quot;E:\GoogleDrive\bin\Debug\Data\ReviewsDB.sdf&quot;;password=123" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

But whenever I move my project (the whole solution) to another PC, I get an error which says the `ReviewsDB.sdf` file path is not correct.

What should I write for data source that won't need to be changed when I move the solution to another PC? I'm using Telerik Open Access to get access to database.

Comment: What about: Data Source=|ApplicationData|\TheDbFile.sdf

Comment: No, I get illegal characters error from the Telerik side.

Comment: You can't have a globally working solution - that's the **whole point** of putting your connection string into the config file, so you can *adapt it as needed*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand you, you need to set relative path to the database in the connection string. If this is the case, with Telerik Data Access and SQL Server CE you can achieve it like this:

1. **Include the .sdf file** in the data access layer **project**.
2. Set the **Copy to Output Directory** property of the **.sdf** file to **Copy always**.
3. Provide the connection string like this:

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
     <add name="ReviewsDBConnection" 
          connectionString="data source=|DataDirectory|\ReviewsDB.sdf;password=123" 
          providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
4. Run the app for a test.

Comment: Would you please let me know how I can set the Copy to Output Directory property of the .sdf file to Copy always? Because I'm using visual studio 2013 and because it doesn't support sql compact edition, I've installed Sql server compact/SQLite and I can't find such a property in it.

Comment: Copy to Output Directory is a property of the .sdf file in the Properties window of Visual Studio. When you include the file in your project, select it, and press F4, Properties window will open for it. There you can choose the appropriate value. [This screencast](http://screencast.com/t/AgWjXXn4tFBS) will provide with an example.